# Wording of the FAQ (Updated)

Tags: discussion

I've updated the [FAQ](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq) to explicitly specify some categories that we do not cover, but I'd like to also include some verbiage on what types of games we **do** cover.

Making this Community Wiki, please feel free to edit the main answer or supply your own as you desire.

2011/01/17 - The main faq section "What kinds of Questions should I not ask here?" has been updated.  This update came from the StackExchange team and [applies to all SE sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

I also added the blurb from the comment below.

Comment: Could we have a link to Brian's in-depth discussion of what counts as a board game? http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/174/if-you-cant-sit-down-at-a-table-and-play-it-its-not-a-board-or-card-game-goo/180#180

Answer (score 2):

You can ask questions about these types of games:

- Classic board games like Monopoly
- Modern "German" style board games such as Settlers of Catan and Puerto Rico
- Traditional Card games like Poker, Bridge and Euchre
- Collectible Card Games like Magic: The Gathering

You can ask questions about these topics:

- Strategy and Tactics
- Rule clarifications, interactions or alterations
- Play Etiquette and other social aspects around playing boardgames
- Storage, Preparation, Enhancements or Repairs
- Game Recommendations (with Restrictions)
- Many other things...

Avoid questions about:

- Trivial information easily procured elsewhere. I.e. "What games where released this year?"
- Social inquiries about our members instead of games. I.e. "What's your favorite game?" - Use the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) such things.

Restrictions concerning Game Recommendations:
To be determined

---

I've included game recommendations even though the decision is not yet final. This is just meant to illustrate how it might look if these questions are approved. - [Kempeth](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/users/174/kempeth)